Matplotlib polar plot: fill_between error
I created a polar plot but can't seem to add a fill_between to my plot.. The ax.plot goes fine but I keep getting this error when adding a fill_between. Any idea how to solve this?

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

# Create a polar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

# Select data
year = 2022
start = f"{year}-01-01"
end = f"{year}-12-31"
data = df.loc[start:end]

# Resample the data to daily frequency and calculate the sum for each day
data = data.resample('D').sum()
data /= 1000 # kWh

# Convert dates to day of year and radians
year_days = len(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'))
day_degree_step = (360 / year_days)

data['day_of_year'] = data.index.dayofyear
data['theta'] = (data['day_of_year'] * day_degree_step * 2 * np.pi) / 360

theta = data['theta'].values
values = data['Afname'].replace(0, 0.1).values

ax.plot(theta, values, label=year)
ax.fill_between(x=theta,
                y1=0,
                y2=values)

# Set the labels for the months with January at the top
month_names = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')  # Set January as the top

I check input arrays theta and values but they do not contain NaN values. they are both np.float64. I also changed 0 values to 0.1 as i thought this might not be "fillable" that didn't help.
This was the results of my inputs array checks:
print(theta.describe(), theta.isna().any())
count    365.000000
mean       3.150200
std        1.816282
min        0.017214
25%        1.583707
50%        3.150200
75%        4.716693
max        6.283185
Name: theta, dtype: float64 False

print(values.describe(), values.isna().any())
count       365.0
mean     8.825373
std      6.693226
min          0.32
25%         4.031
50%         5.698
75%        12.715
max        38.641
Name: Afname, dtype: Float64 False


